# Can I get split screen in Notepad++ like Emacs?

Tags: notepad++, split-window

One of the good points with Emacs is that you can have split the screen so you get two or more views of the same file which allows you to browse around and have a clearer overview of the file. Are there are some plugins or is the same functionality already is built into Notepad++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I view two files side by side in Notepad++](http://superuser.com/q/215917/241386)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

It is built into Notepad++. All you have to do is right-click the tab of the file and say *"Clone to Other View"* and it will split the workspace into two scrollable views of the file, similar to how Emacs does multiple windows. You can also open up two different files in the different views.

Comment: can I make so it only scrolls when I scroll one of the side? As of now they will scroll at the same time when I do so.

Comment: Under the View menu, you can check/uncheck "Synchronize vertical scrolling" and "Synchronize horizontal scrolling" and that should get it doing the behavior you want.

Comment: Currently NP++ seems limited to two windows. In previous versions of there was the possibility to have a real tile-oriented GUI, but it disappeared.

Comment: Having two windows showing with the same content works ok, but the double-click highlighting only works for the window you do the double-clicking in. The other window will not have the highlighting applied.

Comment: In the current version of Notepad++, "Clone to Other View" is under the "Move Document" sub-menu

Answer (score 84):

You can also "rotate" your split view from vertical to horizontal by making :

- a right click on the separation line  (cursor will change to a double arrow)
- and choose from "Rotate to the left" or "Rotate to the right"

Comment: Good one to mention -- this is one of the least discoverable features!

Comment: Some programs do mention features which are not useable, but Notepad++ hides the best features. What a noble reserve :)
Thank You for the mention, user232301!

Answer (score 13):

Just as @Ben Richards as mentioned you should right-click the tab of the file and click "clone to other view".
Initially this would be vertical, you can rotate or "flip" it horizontal by right clicking the dotted line and choose then click "Rotate to the left" or "Rotate to the right"

A point of note it that you can do this for multiple windows

bug a bug i found is that if you originally have multiple tabs open, say A B C. and you cloned A say to AA, if you click tab B or C, AA would still be shown for all of the tabs without a clone. I find this inconvenient.

If you however clone B and or C, you will also have multiple tabs in the cloned windows

[image: notepad++ multiple tabs]

Answer (score 4):

If you right-click on the current tab, or go to View > Move/Clone Current Document, then click "Clone to Other View", it will clone it to the other half of the screen.

Answer (score 4):

Just to point out, there is a detailed description of the built in functionality on the Notepad++ website with pictures and steps for newbies:
http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Multiple_Views

For more than two views the only current option seems to be two instances each with split views (perhaps one snapped to the left side and the other snapped to the right). Would be good if this could be expanded to allow Emacs like functionality... embedded command-line running python on the right, source code on the left.