# view contents of notepad++ tabs simultaneously?

Tags: notepad++

I have notepadplus, and I have multiple tabs, i'd like to see the contents of all the tabs simultaneously e.g. converting them to windows. To a view like with notepad(or any separate windows) where you can Tile Horizontally/Vertically.

**Added clarification**

As you see from my comment, when I say "multiple" I don't mean 1 or 2, I mean more than 2. e.g. could be 5 or 6 or 15 or 30.

This is not a duplicate of [How can I view two files side by side in Notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/215917/how-can-i-view-two-files-side-by-side-in-notepad)   because that one only covers for two files

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I view two files side by side in Notepad++](http://superuser.com/questions/215917/how-can-i-view-two-files-side-by-side-in-notepad)

Answer (score 11):

Like most other tabbed applications, it's as simple as dragging the tabs out of the active application window. When you release the mouse button, Notepad++ will spawn a new window with the tab you just dragged out. Another way to do this is to select the tab you want to break out, and go to **View** -> **Move/Clone Current Document** -> **Move to New Instance**. You can then tile these separate windows as you would like.

You can also drag the tab within the active window to spawn a split-screen view by selecting one of the two "Move to new view" or "Clone to other view" when you release the mouse button after dragging.

Comment: "move to new instance" is greyed out.. (also i'd rather not have to do that for every individual one but for all).  also, if I try dragging a tab out e.g. onto the desktop, I click hold move the mouse, i get the changed mouse cursor, but then I release the mouse button and the tab is still there. split screen isn't what i'm looking for unless you can fit 20 tabs in there (pref) automatically

Comment: I have multiple tabs set to autosave with default names of new 1, new 2 e.t.c.

Comment: The only way I can replicate this is if you haven't yet saved the file. Try saving it first?

Comment: they are set to autosave. You can replicate it if you download the autosave plugin for notepad++ so they save automatically.

Comment: the reason i'm using notepad++ like this is because Saving takes a while 'cos gotta save each file to the correct location, and so I leave that.. sometimes for exampel with notepad I might seee look these 3 files are for this directory, and I can see them all simultaneously, and i'll do file.saveas/ctrl-s) and then paste the DIR in.But still problem with regular notepad is if I don't save and it crashes,I lose it all and it has no autosave optionSo typing into untitled and i'm screwed when it crashes.With notepad++ I have autosave m just create files and write them wthout worryin abouta crash

Comment: I suspect the plugin is the culprit. I can't even get it installed on my version of N++ (latest) due to incompatibilities.

Comment: @gman: My thoughts exactly.

Comment: when I tried I got the message ""Installation Of AutoSave Failed"" so installed it manually - method to install it-  http://www.question-defense.com/2011/02/23/installation-of-autosave-failed-notepad-autosave-plugin-update-fails 1)https://sites.google.com/site/fstellari/nppplugins  2)I downloaded AutoSave_dll_1v30.zip  3)it had 3 files AutoSaveA.dll  AutoSaveU.dll  license.txt   4)A is for the ascii notepadplus  U is for the unicode notepadplus.  So I wanted AutoSaveU.dll not the other.  copied AutoSaveU.dll to the notepad plus plugins directory.

Comment: autosave aside, I did read something about the ""move to new instance" being greyed out if there have been changes since the last save. So maybe, the autosave plugin doesn't set some flag that says there haven't been changes since the last save, and so that option is greyed out. so incompatibility.

Comment: autosave aside. Can it can be done in all tabs simultaneously?  it's extremely inefficient to have to do it for all say 15 tabs individually

Comment: Maybe with a plugin, but N++ doesn't look to natively support exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is a text editor, [NotepadTabs](http://www.notepadtabs.com/) will do what you are trying to do. It is freeware.

[image]

Comment: can you paste a screenshot