# How to get vim like split open (horizontal) in notepad++

Tags: vim, notepad++

I would like to use notepad++ like vim split open in horizontal mode.

Opening files in vertical mode can be done by move file to other view. I need to open files in vertical. Is there any plugin available out.

Answer (score 20):

Open a file to the other view, then rightclick the seperator bar and choose rotate. It will go from horizontal to vertical mode, and back again on another rotate command.

[image]

Comment: How incredibly nonintuitive

Comment: @Veridian true, searched ALL the menus for this and the view menu three times :D

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/q/215917/484629

Comment: For this command to be useful, you also need to set `View/Synchronize Horizontal Scrolling` https://superuser.com/a/587280/626100

Comment: @divenex that is not true. I often use this method when working with scripts that are located in more than one files. Like my main class and my subclasses. The subclasses are in another file, and being able to quickly look up the syntax in the other file makes it very easy to program in the main class.

Answer (score -2):

ctrl-w s will split the screen into 2 parts (windows), one above the other. You can switch windows with ctrl-w ctrl-w.

Read more info with :help window ( :help also opens a new window to display the help info :-)

Comment: ctrl-w in notepad++ will closes the current window, please tell what editor you are referred above.

Comment: Ah, I misread your question, I thought you wanted to do something in vim instead of the other way round.